# Failed to launch chrome with selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver   
webdriver.Chrome()
```

or

**`python -m pytest swim/tests/filename.py`**

give the error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ganesh/.virtualenvs/uniq/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/ganesh/.virtualenvs/uniq/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ganesh/.virtualenvs/uniq/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ganesh/.virtualenvs/uniq/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ganesh/.virtualenvs/uniq/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chrome-driver=2.30,platform=Linux 4.10.0-35-generic x86_64)
```

While running the test cases,browser is not getting launched and what are the things i tried was

- Tried Setting the path of chrome-driver and chromium-browser.
- Tried uninstalling the installing the chrome browser,chrome-driver and selenium in python.
- In lot of suggestions i have seen this Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 so i tried this too.

Any help would be nice ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you didn't set chrome driver directory:-

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
```

[For official documents](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)

Comment: Tried this but problem remains the same.

Comment: @GaneshNagendran you need to install selenium in virtualenv and also chrome driver files should be in the virtualenv folder. [Refrence](http://blog.likewise.org/2015/01/setting-up-chromedriver-and-the-selenium-webdriver-python-bindings-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/)

Answer (score 0):

So, get the chrome drive from here (official chrome page):

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Then unzip it and introduce in your selenium folder->webdriver; mine for example is:

```
C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver

then system property->advanced system settings->Environment Variables->Path
```

[image]
[image]

here click on edit, DON'T DELETE ANYTHING, just add here ";" your path

for example I added

```
;C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver
```

let me know if you need some other help

Comment: After adding the chrome web driver path also it's not launching the browser.Problem is not with the chrome driver because when i launch the terminal outside browser works fine.Only with test cases it is not getting launched.

Comment: mmmm do you have the correct version of chromedrive based on your chrome version? I don't really have anything else in mind :S sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
I have uninstalled Chrome driver and Selenium and re-installed the latest versions of it.Important thing is to set the path for it. Follow the mentioned steps which helped me.

Command to upgrade Selenium:

**pip install -U selenium**

Use the below commands in order to install google chrome:
1.  Add Key:
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
2.  Set repository:
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
3.  Install package:
    sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

4.  check the installed version [ ex:- google-chrome --version]

Install chrome driver
1.  Download chromedriver for linux 64 bit from 
    https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
2.  unzip the file [ ex:- unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip ]
3.  Move the binary to /opt location [ex:- sudo mv chromedriver /opt/ ]
4.  Create symlink the chromedriver to system path [ex:- sudo ln -s /opt/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver ]
6.  check the chromedriver version [ex:- chromedriver --version ]
```